# Boolean , what is the correct answer and why?

Tags: python, boolean

Boolean or "truth-valued" expressions are how we express conditions that control choices and repetition in computer languages.  Consider the following Python Boolean expression, where variables beta and gamma are of type Boolean:

not (beta and gamma)

In any algebraic notation there are usually several different ways of writing the same expression.  For instance, in integer arithmetic the value of expression '4 x (5 + 2)' is numerically equivalent to that of expression '(4 x 5) + (4 x 2)'.

Which of the following Boolean expressions is logically equivalent to the one above?

Answers:
beta or gamma

**(not beta) and (not gamma)**

not (not beta) or gamma

(not beta) or (not gamma)

beta and (not gamma)

**(not beta) and (not gamma)** Is the answer i chose however its incorrect, can someone explain to me the right answer for this is ?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+(a+and+b)

Comment: You might also want to learn [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws - the operator flips when distributed from under negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), `not (A and B)` is `not A or not B`.

You can verify this using simple python script:

```
In [1]: def test(fn):
   ...:     for beta in [False, True]:
   ...:         for gamma in [False, True]:
   ...:             print(f'beta: {beta}, gamma: {gamma}, ans: {fn(beta, gamma)}')
   ...:

In [2]: test(lambda beta, gamma: not (beta and gamma))
beta: False, gamma: False, ans: True
beta: False, gamma: True, ans: True
beta: True, gamma: False, ans: True
beta: True, gamma: True, ans: False

In [3]: test(lambda beta, gamma: not beta or not gamma)
beta: False, gamma: False, ans: True
beta: False, gamma: True, ans: True
beta: True, gamma: False, ans: True
beta: True, gamma: True, ans: False

In [4]: test(lambda beta, gamma: not beta and not gamma)
beta: False, gamma: False, ans: True
beta: False, gamma: True, ans: False
beta: True, gamma: False, ans: False
beta: True, gamma: True, ans: False
```